# Python module does not recognize global alias

Tags: python, python-module

A package within the same directory as my project main has a module that needs to reference a "well-known" module, such as pandas. However, the module does not recognize pandas.

For reference, I am running python 3.7.3.

Here is the directory I have set up:

```
test/
    main.py
    package1/
        __init__.py
        module.py
```

Here is the file `main.py`:

```
import pandas as pd
from package1.module import my_series

print(my_series([1,2,3]))
```

while `module.py` contains

```
def my_series(list1):
    return(pd.Series(list1))
```

I expect the output to be the series associated with this list:

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
```

but instead, I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  2 ||   File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
  3 ||     print(my_series([1,2,3]))
  4 ||   File "/Users/awray_mac/Documents/test/package1/module.py", line 2, in my_series
  5 ||     return(pd.Series(list1))
  6 || NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

What is going on here? What is the proper way to have a submodule like this reference the already imported pandas package from the main file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import pandas in `package1/module.py` as below:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd
```

in the module.py file